# Ipyaggrid Grid not rendered with Voilà

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ag-grid, ipywidgets, voila

I am building an interactive dashboard with widgets on a Jupyter Notebook with the goal of rendering it to a "web-app" with voilà package.

My problem is that the ipyaggrid grid does not get displayed on the voilà rendered page, while the other ipywidgets works fine (more on ipyaggrid here https://dgothrek.gitlab.io/ipyaggrid/). Also, the grid is rendered fine inside the Jupyter Notebook.

Here there's a simple example that I still am not able to display with voilà (while on the jupyter notebook it gets displayed).

```
from ipyaggrid import Grid
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import clear_output
import ipywidgets as widgets

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 2, 3],
    'B': [4, 5, 6],
    'C': [7, 8, 9]
})

grid_options = {
    'columnDefs': [
        {'headerName': col, 'field': col} for col in data.columns
    ],
    'rowData': data.to_dict(orient='records'),
    'pagination': True,
    'paginationPageSize': 5,
    'domLayout': 'autoHeight'
}
grid = Grid(grid_data=data, grid_options=grid_options)

output = widgets.Output()

with output:
    clear_output()
    print('Data is under here')
    display(grid)
    print('Data is above here')

display(output)
```

I have tried not embedding the grid in a output widgets but I see no difference.

Versions I am using:

- Python = 3.12.0
- Voilà = 0.5.5
- ipyaggrid = 0.5.2
- ipywidgets = 8.1.1

On Jupyter Notebook the grid gets displayed
[image: On Jupyter Notebook the grid gets displayed]

On the voilà dashboard the output containing the grid appears empty
[image: On the voilà dashboard the output containing the grid appears empty]

I have tried reading the docs on both packages but I wasn't able to find the problem nor I did find similar issues online.
PS: I am not a seasoned programmer so I wasn't able to dig deep in the Javascript aspect of the libraries also please forgive me for any mistakes.

UPDATE: Using the *Render Notebook with Voilà* in the Jupyter Notebook interface (inside the *View* ribbon) actually displays the grid. The issue described in this post persist when rendering the dashboard through the terminal/powershell i.e. when I write `voila my_script.ipynb` in the terminal

Comment: I was worried at first it wouldn't work since Voila can be strict; however, [here](https://github.com/widgetti/ipyaggrid/issues/40#issue-1797221438) indicates it should. And your code does run where Voila and ipyaggrid are working well together as you can see [here](https://imgur.com/TUlhCmQ). Voila rendering on the right in the screenshot there. I'll describe where and how I tested it as it may allow you to develop without worrying about fixing it now. Or at least give you an option to compare as you troubleshoot.

Comment: @Wayne Thank you for your answer! I've just tried opening my notebook as a stand-alone page (without using vscode), I rendered the script with the "Render Notebook with Voilà" button and it works perfectly, I can see the grid data. I've also tried this with my real project and it works as well.
Still I do not understand what the issue is with what I did earlier: just typing `voila my_script.ipynb` inside the terminal, I've used this method for all my other works involving ipywidgets and I never found any problems.